# PL/sh Procedural Language Handler for PostgreSQL parameters

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Parameters passed to plsh function are not visible.  My function

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION createUserFolder(var text, var1 text) RETURNS text AS '
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1 $2"
' LANGUAGE plsh;
```

Then I call it like

```
Select createUserFolder('Hello', 'World')
```

Output is empty. How to correctly pass parameters to plsh function?

Comment: looks ok to me. should return hello world. maybe default shell is exotic?.. try locating bash and replace first line to it, eg `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately no. The result is the same... http://prntscr.com/i70ifo

Comment: change `EOF` to `'EOF'` on creation. on the top of your putty I see how you create the function - add quotes over EOF there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem. I put all my script into a file and then call it from plsh function

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION createUserFolder(var text, var1 text) RETURNS text AS '
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u vmail /usr/local/sbin/adduser_psql
' LANGUAGE plsh;
```

Also the $1 parameter as I understand is reserved by plsh, so your parameters should start from $2...